# Необработанные исключения в Java

Tags: java

Привет !

Скажите, пожалуйста, где я мог бы узнать как перехватывать необработанные исключения, точнее, мне надо узнать какая возникла ошибка во время выполнения программы и записать эту ошибку допустим в файл.

К примеру, если мы запускаем проект в эклипсе, а в коде имеется ошибка, то она вываливается в консоль, мне нужно почти тоже самое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно поставить обработчик исключений верхнего уровня. Все, что не будет обработано, попадет в него. Читаем, разбираемся [раз](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/exceptions/exceptions_uncaught_handler.shtml), [два](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=229), [три](http://www.javaspecialists.co.za/archive/Issue089.html).

Comment: Спасибо за наводку :)